# What is the easiest NoSQL solution for use?

Tags: java, nosql, solution

About installation (manly, near of zero conf is desired or maybe the possibility to install in a home directory without root privilege), operation, design, queering and integration with java...what is the NoSQL solution more simple and suitable?

Comment: Flat files are easiest, since you already have everything you need.  What are you asking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggest a simple NoSQL database for java project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451935/suggest-a-simple-nosql-database-for-java-project)

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic here. See sister site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoSQL - that is if you're talking of **Not Only SQL** - databases by their very nature solve niche persistence problems by introducing specific optimisations. it is for you, as a developer, to understand what kind of performance benefits you're looking at.

Is it about *scaling out*, *eventual consistency*, *high performance*, *hierarchical document/content* storage, etc? Depending on that you might want to go for a *wide column store* system [HBase, Cassandra], a *graph* based system [Neo4j, HyperGraph], a *document* store [CouchDB, MongoDB], ..., or a host of other options.

You can take a look at an extensive NoSQL guide [here](http://nosql-database.org/), to understand better what will suit your needs.

Something that might be very simple to use, may not solve the persistence problem you're targeting to solve. So, a choice based simply on '*ease of use*' can be detrimental to your cause in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about other products, but you will be up and running with [Project voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) in 10mins with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Tokyo Cabinet requires no config.

http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/

You didn't mention if you wanted a distributed key set, I'm not sure if TK supports this, but it's certainly a good and easy to use solution for a large local persistent hash or map.

Creating a persistent map and storing data is as simple as:

```
   HDB hdb = new HDB();

   // open the database
   hdb.open("mydatabase.tk", HDB.OWRITER | HDB.OCREAT);

   // store record
   hdb.put("foo", "hop");

   hdb.close();
```

[Java API](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/javadoc/)